# R calculate the standard error using bootstrap, Error in is.data.frame(x) :

Tags: r, estimation, standard-error, statistics-bootstrap

I used next program code to estimate the standard error using [bootstrap for Libras Data movement set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/libras/movement_libras.data):

```
mydata<-read.table('C:/Users/Desktop/libra.txt', sep=',', header=TRUE)
head(data)
custom.boot <- function(times, data=mydata) {
  boots <- rep(NA, times)
  for (i in 1:times) {
    boots[i] <- sd(sample(data, length(data), replace=TRUE))/sqrt(length(data))  
  }
  boots
}
# Mean standard error
mean(custom.boot(times=1000))
```

But I got next error:

```
Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Could you help me to figure out the problem and give advice how it can be solved? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a package for bootstraping. Here is a link to the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/boot.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The `mydata` object is being read in as a 395 x 91 `data.frame` which `custom.boot` is struggling with. When I added changed to `data = mydata[, 1]` the function ran without an error. If you want to leave your function as is, I would either loop through every column or stack all the columns into one long column.

EDIT:

If you want to loop through all the columns of this `data.frame`, I would write a loop similar to what you have but one that slices by each column:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(mydata)){
  custom.boot(times=1000, data=mydata[, i])
  print(mean(custom.boot(times=1000)))
}
```

Comment: Thank You for answer, can you explain how can I loop through every column (I can't understand where should I put another cicle)?

Comment: And one more question is this code Ok for classification error estimation?

Comment: Thank You very much for Your help, but I haven't understood in which part of program should I put this loop? I tried to put in in order of # Mean standard error
mean(custom.boot(times=1000))  But I got again error message ("Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'")

Comment: After your suggestions my program looks as follows:require(rpart)
mydata<-read.table('C:/Users/tr/Desktop/HPdati/libratable.txt', sep=',', header=TRUE)
#C:\Users\tr\Desktop\HPdati.libratable
#head(data)
custom.boot <- function(times,  colNumber){ 
  boots <- rep(NA, times)
  for (i in 1:times) {    
    boots[i] <- sd(sample(mydata[,colNumber], length(mydata[,colNumber]), replace=TRUE))/sqrt(length(mydata[,colNumber]))  
  }
  boots
}
for(i in 1:ncol(mydata)){
  custom.boot(times=1000, colNumber=i)
  print(mean(custom.boot(times=1000)))
}
# Mean standard error
mean(custom.boot(times=1000))

Comment: However when I try to execute it I get the following error:  Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> 
 May be You have some ideas how to solve it?